# ConcurrentModificationException for a Java WebSocket server

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I'm building a WebSocket server that handles drawing of objects. Here is how the server's class looks like:

```java
import fmi.whiteboard.models.paths.*;
import jakarta.websocket.*;
import jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/whiteboard",
        encoders = {DrawingEncoder.class, ShapeEncoder.class, PathEncoder.class},
        decoders = {DrawingDecoder.class, ShapeDecoder.class, PathDecoder.class})
public class WhiteboardServer {

    private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session peer) {
        peers.add(peer);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session peer) {
        peers.remove(peer);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void broadcastShape(Drawing drawing, Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        for (Session peer : peers) {
            if (!peer.equals(session)) {
                peer.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(drawing);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And here is how the ReactJS component that handles drawing looks like:

```
export default function Whiteboard() {
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  const ws = useMemo(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/backend_war/whiteboard");
    socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
    return socket;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    ws.onmessage = (evt: MessageEvent) => {
      const data: SocketResponse = JSON.parse(evt.data);
      if (data && data.shapes) {
        canvas?.current?.loadPaths(data.shapes);
      }
    };

    ws.onerror= (err) => console.log(err);
    
  }, [ws]);

  const onDraw = (message: CanvasPath[]) => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ shapes: message }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReactSketchCanvas
        ref={canvas}
        style={styles}
        onUpdate={(paths) => setPaths(paths)}
        strokeWidth={4}
        strokeColor="red"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

The app works fine for 2-3 seconds but as soon I start drawing a lot more shapes, the socket server crashes with `ConcurrentModificationException` on the line with `for (Session peer : peers)`.

If it is of any help, I'm using Java 11 and Tomcat 10 as the server.

Answer (score 1):

Collections.synchronizedSet creates a Set where single item access are synchronized. This concerns methods such as get, add, remove, etc.
However, the iterator isn't synchronized. You obtain ConcurrentModificationException when another thread modifies the collection while iteration is in progress.

You have two solutions. Either protect the look with a synchronized block like this:

```
synchronized(peers) {
  for (Session peer: peers) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Or, better, switch to ConcurrentHashSet, which guarantees optimized access by multiple threads without never throwing ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 0):

When you synchronize and existing collection with `Collections.synchronizedSet` it only synchronizes the methods to access the data such as `get()`, `set()`... and not the iterator. Therefore you need to synchronize the iterator as well like this for example

```
synchronized(peers){
        for (Session peer : peers) {
            if (!peer.equals(session)) {
                peer.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(drawing);
            }
        }   
    }
```

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It fixes the exception that is thrown but the server still stops working after drawing a simple line. The bad thing is that there is not exception message, either. In the browser it just says `WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state`. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I don't as this looks more like a socket implementation issue rather than ConcurrentModification one